how to add Siri Shortcuts automatically without user record phrase

I have added 3-4 Siri Shortcuts using user Record Phrase and use them, but now I am trying to implement those Siri Shortcuts automatically witout user record phrase just like some other apps like zomato. I have tried to use this code but it's not working

INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions
once I install this app it will automatically added all my siri intent, I want to acheive that.


Getting this error

ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Sample phrase 'Siri, start a boulder climb with ascent' cannot contain 'siri'
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Sample phrase 'Siri, start a boulder workout with ascent' cannot contain 'siri'
check screenshot for reference.
I have tried INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions but its no use.

My colleague also faced same sort of error. Did you find the solution?
